# Rails 3.1 Netzke Asset Pipeline Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, symlink, assets, netzke

Walking through this tutorial and am having problems with Rails Asset Pipeline.

http://blog.writelesscode.com/blog/2010/06/14/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/

I make the symlink:

```
> ln -s ~/code/ext-4.0.2a app/assets/extjs
```

I also tried

```
> ln -s ~/code/ext-4.0.2a public/extjs
```

I get this error both ways:

```
/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css isn't in paths:
    /Users/ot/PM/app/assets/images,
    /Users/ot/PM/app/assets/javascripts,
    /Users/ot/PM/app/assets/stylesheets,
    /Users/ot/PM/vendor/assets/stylesheets,
    /Users/ot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@pm/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.16/vendor/assets/javascripts,
    /Users/ot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@pm/gems/web-app-theme-0.8.0/app/assets/images,
    /Users/ot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@pm/gems/web-app-theme-0.8.0/app/assets/stylesheets,
    /Users/ot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@pm/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-1.0.4/lib/assets/javascripts
```

I have been playing with symlinks for an hour and am getting no where.  It is still one directory off.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception like "[somefile] isn't in path" is debug exception.

It arise because recommended to keep all scripts in assets pipeline directories.

All you need is turn off debug mode for asset pipelines.

Change in config/environments/development.rb string:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

to

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Comment: Genius, my friend. I set config.assets.debug = false yesterday but did not realize there was another config.assets.debug = true later in that file.  Thank you!